# Implementing Withings api in android

Tags: android, withings

I am trying to implement the withings api in android. Able to do the authentication part through "google auth" implementation but not able to access the api as "oauth_nonce" is unknown and I have no idea how to generated it. If you know the process then please do share and if you have implemented withings api using any method then please do share.

Answer (score 0):

The oauth_nonce is a random string and it must be unique.

I'm developing an hybrid app so my code to generate the oauth_nonce in AngularJS is :

```
.factory('RandomFactory', function() {
  return ({
    string: function(length, chars) {
      var result = '';
      for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
      return result;
    }
  })

var oauth_nonce = RandomFactory.string(32, "1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm");
```

But I think you can easily do the same in Java.